# how to capture jenkins changelist between two successful build

Tags: jenkins, perforce

My requirement is to get the perforce change-list details from the last successful build to the latest successful build.

For Eg: I have Jenkins builds like below

JOB1:build#112 - Successful

JOB1:build#113 - Failed

JOB1:build#114 - Failed

JOB1:build#115 - Successful

I want Jenkins to show all p4 change-list in the build#115 that went in for build#113 and build#114 . Jenkins always show the p4 change-list between the last two build regardless of failure or successful build. I need this to generate the report that the particular successful build has these many p4 check-ins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one jenkins plugin which solved my query.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Changes+Since+Last+Success+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming from change-list you mean to say diff of configs between two successive build's.

For this we have [JobConfigHistoryPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin)
where you can see all the config changes in GUI and can revert to any previous build config.
Hope it helps.

Edit:

Did you try [PerforcePlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Perforce+Plugin) or [P4Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/P4+Plugin) ?

Comment: JobConfigHistoryPlugin  shows config changes of job configuration. I need changes list from perforce check-ins . Jenkisn job should show p4 changelist between two successful bulids Currently jenkins shows the changes between the latest and 2nd latest. 2nd latest could be the failed build.

Comment: yes, i am using this plugins and this is why i can see the p4 changelist between two consecutive job. But my requirement is get changelist between two successful build. two successful build can be consucutive build or it may have failed builds in between. Please see my example above.